# Кэширование внешних API в Angular PWA и окружение

Tags: javascript, angular2, кэширование, pwa

Можно ли при использовании *@angular/pwa* кэшировать внешние API (домен приложения и API не совпадает). Если да то каким образом должна выглядеть коyфигурация *ngsw-config.json*, если например нужно закэшировать ответ от *somedomain.com/api/user/5*.

При этом somedomain.com прописан в enviroment. Есть ли встроенные средства для того что бы подружить enviroment и *ngsw-config.json*.

Comment: По поводу твоего первого вопрос есть много статей в интернете, вот самая первая ссылка в гугле - https://christianlydemann.com/how-to-cache-http-requests-in-an-angular-pwa/ . по поводу второго вопроса - а что тебе мешает прописать домен в конфиге? сервис воркер то включается в продакшене через `enabled`, фактически у тебя есть 1 энвайронмент, то есть продакшн

Comment: @overthesanity Бывают кейсы когда требуется поднять стенд, для тестирования и продакшена, выходит что средствами сборки Angular CLI, такую сборку сделать не удасться и требуется писать дополнительные скрипты подмешивающие в сборку правильный ngsw-config.json.

В представленной статье не описанно как должена выглядить концигурация с внешнем API расположенном на другом домене. Тут вопрос в том как я должен описывать эти API, с протоколом или без, и будет ли вообще это работать.
Например:
"somedomain.com/api/user/5" или 
"http://somedomain.com/api/user/5"